# Python sending email won't work, and is giving long error messages

Tags: python, email, smtp, mime

I'm testing a python script to send e-mail to myself:

```
import smtplib
fromaddr = '----------@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = '----------@gmail.com'
msg = 'GRRRRR!!!!!!'
username = '----------@gmail.com'
password = '----------'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Where "----------" means "private information." This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ms.py", line 10, in <module>
    server.login(username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 615, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvXa\n5.7.14 z7t5LRUd-e-nGxiMetNBY2KaLd8EP3SJVhw2EwccDQjlUi0FxHegAH2YrpvKdYIX2lHz9N\n5.7.14 cMZ_w8kPxuXXhBPMbXA26tWu_HM0tt_4IC8aEct5VRz7z1J22epkLWXUx-COwh4rt2K2-_\n5.7.14 1Lw71Ag70CBpsqYpfzScV-_mF7zHl_NFRflAn5sFnPftR_bX6hhGAHxj5rz1bx0U44sByk\n5.7.14 t-arL3mQhKu-nfFzkcIvjlzuUh3w> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14 Learn more at\n5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 p18sm2343352qkh.10 - gsmtp')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right username and password? The error tells you "Please log in via your web browser and then try again" + it gives to a link to the Google help about username and password not being accepted: [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754)

Comment: This isn't your immediate problem, but your message does not contain any headers. Or rather, it contains only a header, and that header is `GRRRRR!!!!!!`, which is not a valid header. Actually it does not include a body.

Comment: Also, you need to activate allow sign in from insecure sources in your google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need:

`server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com:465')`

instead of:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
```

and probably don't need the .ehlo ()

See also https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833